# Javascript to detect safari and chrome on mac

Tags: javascript, browser-detection

Does anyone have any javascript code to detect **Safari** and **Chrome** running on **Mac OS** so I can apply css for each browser?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/9851769/1823841

Comment: This is a bad idea mostly. Care to tell us a bit more about your use case?

Comment: This is a very bad idea, unless you care to explain why you are doing this, and why feature detection won't be the better path, you will get the wrath of the community! :)

Comment: For example I need it to properly use 3rd party java applet ;)

Comment: @thg435 I agree, BUT there are a lot of scenarios where this is necessary, for example when Safari on Mac messes up fonts (because Mac renders differently heights etc.). It's bad practive for sure, but if your 50.000€-client wants his custom webfonts, well, then you do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";    

var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera') >= 0;
    // Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
    var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
    var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
    var isChrome = !!window.chrome;                          // Chrome 1+
    var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;                            // At least IE6

    if(OSName == "MacOS" && isChrome == true) 
    {
        alert('chrome on MAC OS')
    }
```

Comment: You forgot the "running on Mac OS" part.

Comment: Why do you have: if(OSName == "MacOS" && isChrome == true) twice?

Comment: isChrome no longer returns true on Mac with Chrome.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of browser detection, you should go for feature detection.  You should also give a try for [Modernizr.js](http://modernizr.com/)